# Display value in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I have created a variable x=11.5. I want now to display x in the viewer pane in RStudio.

Is there a way how to display it and adjust fonts and colors?

```
x <- 11.5
```

Comment: check out the library called `kableExtra`

Comment: You'd need to create output that is suitable for the Viewer Pane, e.g html or Rmd, etc -> see [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane) for more info

Comment: I edited my code. It is a simple example but i don't get the way how to display. I know how to display tables etc. with certain packages but don't get it for a simple value.

Comment: I undesrtood the question more in the lines of `x <- 11.5; x`   but now I see what's up....

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
x <- 11.5
library(htmltools)
html_print(x)
```

This displays just the number in the viewer pane:

[image]

If you want to change fonts etc., you'd use HTML type things to do that.  For example, wrap the number in `<a style="font-size: 100px"></a>` using

```
html_print(a(x, style="font-size: 100px"))
```